# Upgrade Xcode Project - Storyboard Constraints Disabled

Tags: ios, xcode

I have inherited an Xcode project that is at least one year old. Everything builds fine but when I try to use Xcode Storyboard Constraints, the feature appears to be disabled. The bottom toolbar is not displayed and if you go to Editor->Pin all the options are greyed out. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select "Use Auto Layout" in the storyboard properties.